# Navigating top-level Lisp/Clojure forms in Vim

Tags: vim, clojure, lisp, slimv

I use  Vim for Clojure development. I'd like a movement key or mapping that will jump through the top-level forms in the buffer. `{` and `}` are close, but stop if there's a blank line in the middle of the form. slimv-paredit's `(` and `)` move within a top-level forms. Here's an example:

```
(def foo :bar)
(defn plus [x y]
  (+ x y))

(def yum :cat)
```

Assuming the cursor starts at the top, I'd like to jump to the opening paren of `foo`, `plus`, and then `yum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added mappings `[[` and `]]` for moving to the previous/next defun in Slimv's paredit.vim. Please fetch it from the [Slimv repository](https://bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv).

Comment: Nice. Two issues: on line 41 of [this file](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/blob/develop/src/seesaw/core.clj#L41) (the `(defn native! ...` line), "back" doesn't seem to work. Also it stops on parens in comments. See the copyright notice at the top of the same file. Otherwise, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the bug report, I have fixed it. If you still experience problems, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a quick vim macro to do what you want. Put this in your .vimrc:

`map \n /^(<CR>`

When you press \n, you'll hop to the next form that starts on a line.

Comment: did you miss a `(` in there? For me, this just goes to the start of each line.

Comment: Er, yeah I did. Thanks, fixed. I have no idea how that happened!